# JQuery, have problems using variable as a selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I was given these set of practice instructions:

Write a selector which finds the UL within the tasks div and store this into a variable named task_list.

```
    var task_list = $('div#tasks ul');
```

then the next one got me confused:

Write a second selector line which finds all children within task_list that have the class name completed. Store this into a variable named all_completed.
Use the detach() method. Call detach() on your all_completed variable.

```
     var all_completed = $(task_list).children('li.completed').detach();
```

or

```
   $(all_completed).detach(task_list);
```

Can someone please help me?  Is this asking me to create a variable and use it as a selector in jQuery?  If so, how do I do this??

Comment: I think your first version should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`task_list` is already a jquery object, you don't need to re-jquery (is that a term?) it.

```
var all_completed = task_list.children('li.completed').detach();
```

Comment: I think jQuery determines pretty quickly that its argument is already a jQuery object, and just returns it. So there's little harm in re-jquerying.

Comment: I'm not understanding how task_list is already jQuery-ied.... Is it because I assigned it a jQuery statement?  I thought making a jQuery variable was done $variable = ('variablenowjQuery');??

Comment: When you `$(".anything")` you are creating a jquery object using the selector, in this case `.anything`